# Database design or architecture suitable for storing logs, real time reporting and utilized as log correlation engine

Tags: database-design, logging, reporting, bigdata, correlation

The problem i face is related to storing and retrieving reasonably fast millions of logs. I work on collecting everyday logs from firewalls, intrusion detection and prevention systems, application logs, user activity etc., storing them on a database, perform real time reporting and correlating them for identifying intrusions etc. So after working and building a system with syslog and mysql i found out that the bottlenck at the moment is the database. I have experience only on relational database. On the other hand i am totally lost on all those technologies that exist and came to my knowledge in the database field.

So the NoSQL databases (mongo, cassandra etc) will be any better and outperform tranditional databases (MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL etc)? From what I have read until now there are no aggregation functions and consequently the reporting will not be feasible, am i right?

Dataware Houses is any better to my needs? I know that they are used for reporting but not for real time. Is it true or there are any implementation today that support maybe near real time that might be acceptable? I found out that is more or less a different way of designing database schema and that the traditional databases could be excellent candidates for that. Is this true?

Also I was proposed to create table partitions but not using the database feature that exists in databases. The idea is to use seperate tables based on size probably and create procedures that store and update indexes for the seperated tables and generally manipulate them to speed things up whenever i need to perform a join or aggregation. Does anyone heard or used something similar to this? Because at first it seemed totally not appliable such a solution to me.

In the end is it possible to migrate some of the above technologies to have better and more balanced results?

I know that it is a big issue. However i see that my up to date knowledge and experience in RDBMS is not enough for solving the problem. And since the technologies are so many i need to hear opinions, discuss it and be guided by people that had some experience in the past. Also discuss pros and cons of certain approaches. Are there any forums that you can propose which can be helpful to me? One last thing is that the measurement rank of data volume would be of terabytes, not petabytes, so this might exclude some of the technologies like hadoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you settle on a storage method, the question is what type of analysis you want to do.

For aggregation oriented workloads and the volume you're talking about, a traditional rdbms like oracle, sql server or postgresql running on a beefy server should do. They have native support for partitioning and other DWH techniques (such as materialized views) which will save you the time of cobbling it together yourself. For example the oracle query optimizer will take into account partitioning when generating a new query plan.

As reporting front-end you can go for one of the commercially available ones or create your own. Some options are obiee, SQL server reporting services, cognos and pentaho (free)
They all support cross-db reporting (combining DWH + operational store) to some extent.

If you need instant answers for arbitrary queries involving aggregations on large volumes (billion row datasets) you could look into teradata, netezza, vertica and the like. These tend to cost quite a lot.

If you often want instant answers for arbitrary queries involving aggregations on smaller datasets, look into [qlikview](/questions/tagged/qlikview). They have a powerful in-memory analysis tool. I believe it's free for single-person usage.

If it's not simply a matter of adding up numbers but analyzing complex relationships (graph like analysis) on large volumes, you're out of luck. Old solutions don't scale well or are expensive, new ones are often hit and miss. It's going to be expensive either way. Without knowing how you want to correlate events, it's hard to recommend anything. I'm not aware of any general solution.

Personally, I'd go with postgres (backend) + pentaho and [qlikview](/questions/tagged/qlikview) (both front-end) with kettle for traditional ETL and hadoop or custom code to precalculate results for more complicated analysis. In postgres split up your data in an operational store and a DWH.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of questions!

**Q1:** Does NoSQL have aggregation?

**A1:** I know Mongo has aggregation, but the last time I used it, it wasn't particularly fast compared to relational databases. Can't speak to Cassandra. Lots of people use Mongo to store structured logs and report.

**Q2:** What about data warehouses?

**A2:** You're right that a data warehouse can exist in a relational database. It's just a different way of structuring the data and thinking about it.

Have you thought about keeping a snapshot of time in a real time relational database and then archiving older logs?

For example, maybe at 10 million, you start shipping out the oldest log entries to a data warehouse and this guarantees that you are always only looking at the most recent 10 million log entries, which should be fast.

Comment: Ok I see your point here. Lets say that I implement the data warehouse approach you propose. So there is for instance a need to produce statistical reports over the last month, and the rows that were received and uploaded to the database where over 10 millions. Consiquently I must apply aggregation functions to the snapshot of real time logs and combine them with result that is produced from statistical analysis over the archived ones (in the data warehouse). Is this possible or there is a different way to solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

***"I was proposed to create table partitions but not using the database feature that exists in databases. The idea is to use seperate tables based on size probably and create procedures that store and update indexes for the seperated tables and generally manipulate them to speed things up whenever i need to perform a join or aggregation"***
This is good approach, you can create new tables hourly, daily based on the load. Mysql uses table locks, queries on large tables will take more time so increases query waiting time. Multiple tables encourages to do parallel queries, for example 
 *Assume that tables are created hourly, to get one day stats you can have two threads, 1st thread will get the stat from hour-0 to hour-6 and second thread will get the stats from hour-7 to hour-12. There is no waiting on table lock.* 
 you can have multiple DB servers to handle more load

Answer (score 0):

You maybe better off looking at Hadoop/Cassandra for aggregation if your data size demands it.

Mongo's aggregation when I used it was single threaded not sure if it has changed - that explains the slowness as the collection size grows.

If you are looking at multi data center replication with bullet proof disaster recovery, then Cassandra scores some points over Hadoop as the architecture is more democratic than master-slave, which tends to have single point of failures.

Both Cassandra and Hadoop have been battle tested by companies that store a lot of unstructured data. Are they more complex than SQL, hell yes. They are a different breed of databases that solve a different breed of problems. Hadoop is more of an ecosystem, that will take you an year to master - than a database. A point to note is that Cassandra also needs pruning of the SSTables to get decent performance. The issue is more pronounced as the data size grows.

Mongo is more suited when you need to do adhoc queries (on fields which are indexed).